# Need to Get Current Slide number - Basic JQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using [Basic JQuery Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/), How can I get the active/current number, I am using multiple sliders.

```
var bannerslides = $('#banner-slides').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide'
});
var bannerslides2 = $('#banner-slides2').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide'
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$scope.update = function() {
//Need to get slider number here, like
console.log(bannerslides.index());
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner-slides">   
   <ul class="bjqs>
       <li>
           ...
       </li>
       <li>
           ...
       </li>
   </ul>
```

I actually need it in on a click event of button to decide an action.

Comment: On which button click you have to get  active slide?

Comment: @Sadikhasan  Answered. pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified plugin to get current slide number.

Just added a function to return active/current slide.

Above the `init(); return this;` at the end of the file `bjqs-1.3.js`

Add the following function.

```
this.getactiveslide = function() {
   return state.currentindex;  
};
```

And called this `console.log(bannerslides.getactiveslide());`

Hope this helps and saves someones time in future.